# Finding an element using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

How can I find this element? I am using selenium and coding in python.

These are the elements details:

```
Xpath = //*[@id="545711682"] 
CSS-selector = #\35 45711682
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="545711682"]')
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="545711682"]')
```

When I use `elements` instead of `element` the code doesn't fail, but I am assuming I find bunch of elements instead of one and thats why its not clickable.

[Here is the link](http://gmu.libcal.com/booking/FenStudy6), and these is the html part that I am trying to find:

When selected:

```
<a href="#" class="lc_rm_a lc_rm_t" data-seq="33526109" id="545711682" onclick="return showBookingForm(this.id,'4705','12:00pm - 12:30pm, Tuesday, June 13, 2017', '30');" style="width: 30px; float:left; display:block;" title="4705, 12:00pm to 12:30pm, Tuesday, June 13, 2017">&nbsp;</a>
```

When not selected:

```
<a href="#" class="lc_rm_a" data-seq="33526109" id="545711682" onclick="return showBookingForm(this.id,'4705','12:00pm - 12:30pm, Tuesday, June 13, 2017', '30');" style="width: 30px; float:left; display:block;" title="4705, 12:00pm to 12:30pm, Tuesday, June 13, 201
7">&nbsp;</a>
```

Comment: instead of the picture of the site, please include the link itself, thank you.

Comment: This is the link http://gmu.libcal.com/booking/FenStudy6   and this is the html part <a href="#" class="lc_rm_a lc_rm_t" data-seq="33526109" id="545711682" onclick="return showBookingForm(this.id,'4705','12:00pm - 12:30pm, Tuesday, June 13, 2017', '30');" style="width: 30px; float:left; display:block;" title="4705, 12:00pm to 12:30pm, Tuesday, June 13, 2017">&nbsp;</a>

Comment: I'm new here, and trying to get hold of how to post properly. did you get the information or is it clear?

Comment: Sorry friend, I became busy on another work matter. But yes, I have understood your question, I'm glad you found an answer.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the element wasn't present when I was looking for it

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

and this is the code that got it done:

```
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="545711682"]'))).click()
```